# Azure Function halts without error: Runs locally in VS Code extension but not in cloud deployment

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-functions

We are facing a difficulty in executing a Function App.
This Function was developed in Python 3.9 and is triggered by a timerTrigger that accesses various endpoints of a API, which is public domain and has ample capacity for requests. When it reaches a certain amount of information, it inserts the data into the database and continues with the requests.

When we run it through the Azure extension in VS Code, we have the expected execution, as planned, and the respective information in the database. See the log image below.

[runing in vs code, inserted many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGXkZ.png)

However, when it is executed in the cloud, it returns or terminates the execution suddenly without generating an error, as if it were working normally, but the logs show that not all steps were executed. We do not understand how it simply stops the execution and closes the app as if everything were functioning.

[at azure, inserted just a few](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKtJl.png)

As this is a very specific issue and without any error feedback, we have been working for some time trying to solve the problem, both by breaking the function into smaller parts or doing it step by step, but we have not obtained different results.

We appreciate your attention.

We also tried to make the Function App work with a dedicated IP, assuming it could be an error in the application's connection with Azure, considering that other users could use the IP to connect to the same API and cause conflicts.

Therefore, we request support to check and help us solve this problem, since we understand that the code and the project are working perfectly when executed locally, and we do not receive any error feedback or anything similar when it is in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are running your function app on the Consumption tier.
Function apps running on a Consumption plan have a maxium timeout of 10 minutes. This includes even time triggered functions

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout

[image]

Here's how you can change the plan:

- Go to the Azure portal and navigate to your function app.
- Click on the "Function app settings" link.
- Under the "Configuration" section, click on the "General settings" link.
- Change the "App Service Plan" to the desired plan (e.g., Premium).
- Save the changes.